# How to create in TelerikMVC3 using  jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, telerik-mvc

I developed a TelerikMVC3 application using JqueryMobile, by following this video tutorial - [Jquery Mobile sample](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4aplEitjK4). But, when I run the application it shows only a White screen and there no controls.

Please help.

Comment: that most likely means you have a javascript error on your page, which stops jQM controls from rendering. Check Javascript Console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

It been a while since this question was asked. But for those still looking for an answer.. Maybe this might help:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/general/telerik-mvc-jquery-mobile.aspx